# Blazor WASM failing to run. Not finding dependent assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

The hosted wasm app (wasm client, hosting server, shared project) has been working fine for a long time. Recently it started having issues running. It will fail processing the Program Main looking for dependent assemblies. I've tried as much as I can to track down the cause without digging through the aspnetcore webassembly source.

The assembly that the browser console shows an error for is not always the same. In the case of assemblies that are dependents of dependent assemblies, I've tried referencing those from the main project and it doesn't make a difference. If I look in the browser cache I can see all the assembly dlls and pdb files downloaded. The one thing I have noticed is the assembly name in cache (and in the blazor.boot.json) is ALWAYS changed to all uppercase for the assembly that is failing to load. It's as if something server side is messing with the assembly name. It gets downloaded to the browser with the uppercase name. The exception is it can't find the assembly with pascal cased name. If someone also wants to point me in the right direction on the github repo where the server generates the blazor.boot.json manifest and also the are in the webassembly source where the manifest is consumed, assemblies fetched and loaded, I could poke around through the source to see if something looks to be the cause.

I'll probably post this in the repo issues in case this was caused by a recent version change. I know for a while I was on the 7.0.5 runtime then VS 2022 updated along with the SDK and moved me to 7.0.9. It seems to be nearly impossible to revert versions as the SDK installation in windows is tied to the version of VS installed.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Dgc.External.Ui.BlazorWasm.Shared, Version=2023.7.14.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

*Where Dgc.External.Ui.BlazorWasm.Shared is the shared class library project between the client and server projects*

[image: Chrome Browser cache]

*Note in the browser cache screenshot, there are some assemblies Uppercased. The problem assemblies are ALWAYS uppercased*

Any ideas would be helpful. It is crashing before the Program Main is executing my code currently. I have a try/catch that it is not even hitting there.

Update: After going into the client project bin folder the problem assemblies are also uppercase there as well. I don't know what the source of those bad compilations are. If I delete the uppercase assemblies and re-build the project they are normal cased and the project works as expected. I tried building the client project, building/running the server project and changing one of the assembiles while running to see if any of those methods cause a bad compile. Nothing happened so far. If anyone has any ideas on a certain condition that would cause VS/MSBuild to compile incorrectly, lmk and I can test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your post on the Blazor ASP.NET Github. I encountered the same behavior and I already tested a lot on how to cure it. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Blazor-Webassembly-published-assembly-fi/10423695)

It seems to be a bug when rebuilding or publishing a project. Until it's fixed, I changed the following VS2022 option:

Open VS2022 options -> go to Projects and Solutions -> Compile and run -> change the first option, "max number of parallel project builds" to 1 -> save.

Then before rebuilding again, I clean the whole project (Build -> clean ...). Then it seems to work for some time again.

Before publishing, I delete all "bin" and "obj" folders. Then it works to build correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I did your suggestion. At the very least it seems like a clean/build is needed. sometimes I have to manually delete the bin and obj folders. Would you mind posting here if you hear that this is permanently fixed?

Comment: I was stuck with this error for 2 days. This worked for me. especially changing the option "max number of parallel project builds" to 1 in Visual studio 2022